# Place text in lower right corner of a button

Tags: html, css, button, text-align

I've been searching for the answer on how to do this for awhile now. Basically is what I want is to place text in the lower right corner of a button. This is what I have so far. I have the text aligned to the right, but it is still in the middle of the button. How can I align it with the bottom as well?

```
.button{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QavgZ/

html:

```
<a class="button">text</a>
```

css:

```
.button{
  height: 14px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding-top: 36px;
}
```

the right alignment you found out already. For the bottom alignment I set the height of the button, text and fontsize all to the same value. I then added top padding to make the height become the desired 50px again (actual height = height+padding).

Comment: This works for specific button content. But it's not very flexible for dynamic content. http://jsfiddle.net/QavgZ/1/

Comment: you are absolutly right about that @showdev. You could go for the table cell solution as well, but I am not a big fan of that. And buttons do rarely have more then one line of text in my experience. Although an overflow:hidden should probably be added to make sure